# Concatenate a 4d array with 2d array in python

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, feature-extraction, word-embedding

I have an array (of features extracted from an image) with the dimension (1,2048,7,7) and a word embedding (from fastText encoding) with the dimension (1,300). I want to concatenate these arrays to get an array with dimension (1,2348,7,7). How do I go about this?

Comment: I guess `numpy.repeat` or `numpy.tile` can be used to increase the (1, 300) dimension to (1, 300, 7, 7), then use `numpy.concatenate` to concatenate the two arrays.

Comment: Can you provide a code example to perform this?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation for all of these functions. Doesn't that clarify it for you?

Comment: Yeah, it did. I was stuck in the beginning but I got it to work in the end, thank you!

Comment: You can self-answer your question with your solution if you want, e.g. for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that concatenate doesn't do broadcasting.  Fortunately, assignment does do broadcasting, so you can just build your result.

```
result = np.empty((1, 2348, 7, 7))
result[:,:2048] = image
result[:,2048:,:,:] = fast_text_encoding
```

Comment: It still said that array with dim (1,300) cannot be assigned to the array with dim (1,300,7,7).

Comment: The assignment works after using numpy.tile. Thank you!

Comment: Just pointing out that numpy.tile has to create a temporary array to hold the expanded fast_text_encoding.  The solution above avoids the temporary array, at the expense of being a little bit more obscure.